# How to execute AjaxStart in a common javascript by selected page only

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a Javascript file that has an ajaxStart function that is used by all pages.

My problem is I want only selected pages to access the ajaxStart via button click. How should I implement this?

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(document).ajaxStart(function()
    {
        $("#overlay").css
        ({
        "display"           : "block",
        "background-color"  : "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)",
        "width"             : $(document).width(), 
        "height"            : $(document).height(),
        "position"          : "absolute",
        "z-index"           : 99999 
        })
    });
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function()
    {
        $("#overlay").css("display", "none");
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="overlay" style="display:none">
    <img src='loading.gif'/>
</div>
```

The code above displays a loading gif inside div on button click. The button click function is in different HTML pages.

Comment: How does the code look like?

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: $(document).ready is executed when the page loads. If you want to use ajaxStart only on button click you have to move it out of the document.ready function and attach it to the button with <button onclick="myfunction()"></button>

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear to me if you want the overlay on button click additionally triggered on clicking a button to the onload functionality or instead of it.

Either way this is how you would trigger it via Button:

HTML:

```
<button onclick="overlay()">Click me for Overlay</button>
```

JS:

```
function overlay(){
    $(document).ajaxStart(function()
    {
        $("#overlay").css
        ({
        "display"           : "block",
        "background-color"  : "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)",
        "width"             : $(document).width(), 
        "height"            : $(document).height(),
        "position"          : "absolute",
        "z-index"           : 99999 
        })
    });
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function()
    {
        $("#overlay").css("display", "none");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't put that in the same script as the other general script, in this case in your 'common.java'. Put it in another file like 'ajaxstart.java' or something and only put it in the selected pages that you want to use.

However, using this ajaxStart event will trigger all any ajax call in all the pages, even on those call that you do not want to show the css. I recommend you manually add the css on each ajax call that you made, for example:

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    // Button click, calling ajax function
    $("#overlay").css
    ({
    "display"           : "block",
    "background-color"  : "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)",
    "width"             : $(document).width(), 
    "height"            : $(document).height(),
    "position"          : "absolute",
    "z-index"           : 99999 
    });

    $.post('script.php', 
    {
        variable: variable,
        char: char,
    }, function(result) {
        alert(result);
        // When ajax call complete
        $("#overlay").css("display", "none");
    });
});
```